# change number of columns/ products per row for specific woocommerce product category in php

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am using Woocommerce 3.3.3 and trying to change the number of columns for a specific product category and not the other product categories.  I have tried several code options, but they all apply the change in columns to all categories.  Here is one of thing I've tried.

```
/* change columns to 1 for newsletter issues prod cat*/

add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        if ( is_product_category('newsletter-issues')) {
            return 1;
        } else { // for other archive pages and shop page
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the bellow function you can set product list column and number of product per category page.

```
    /*  Set product columns for specific category */

    add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns'); 
    if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
        function loop_columns() {
            if ( is_product_category('a')) {
                return 3;
            } else if ( is_product_category('c')) {
                return 2;
            }else{
                return 4;   
            }
        }
    }

    /* Set product per page for specific category */

    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'cdx_woocommerce_products_per_page', 1, 50 );
    function cdx_woocommerce_products_per_page( $query ) {

        if( $query->is_main_query() && isset($query->query['product_cat'])){

            switch($query->query['product_cat']){

                case 'a':
                    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '3' );
                break;
                case 'c':
                    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
                break;
                default:    
                    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '4' );
            }

        }
    }
```

- Here **a** and **c** is product category slug. You can change it as per your required category slug.
- You need to add this code inside your theme function.php

Comment: Did you check the solution ? let me know if you face any issue regarding the above solution. I have tested this in my local server and it is working there.

Answer (score 0):

As per the @Codextent code, In **product columns for specific category** It doesn't work, I think it is caused by the woocommerce new verison. currently I am using 5.0 version of woocoomerce.

the other ***showing product per page is working***

here it seems,

```
if ( is_product_category('a')) {
            return 3;
        } else if ( is_product_category('c')) {
            return 2;
        }else{
            return 4;   
        }
```

To work, changed above code to this

```
                if ( has_term( 'a', 'product_cat' ) ) {
                return 4; // 4 products per row
                }else{
                    return 2; 
                }
```

Happy Coding :)