# Products in 2 rows instead 3, but just for selected product category

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm working on site where I need to setup products to be showed in to 2 rows, instead of the default 3 for all other products categories. I searched into Stack and Google and found this [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456778/change-number-of-columns-products-per-row-for-specific-woocommerce-product-cate) answer, where the asnwer was writen in this function:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns'); 
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        if ( is_product_category('torres-elevadoras')) { // wanted product category
            return 2;
        } 
}
```

This doesn't seem to take effect when inserting into the functions.php file into my theme. Are some coding changes into latest Woo 3.4.1 that making this function not work anymore?

EDIT: When inserting this CSS, it shows me products into two columns, but for all category. How to apply for wanted product category?

```
.woocommerce div.product {
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix myself using this CSS rule:

```
.term-torres-elevadoras.woocommerce div.product {
width:50%;
}
```

To explain how i fixed. on category page, press Ctrl+U and search for this string into code:

```
<body class="archive
```

and will found something like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVWvl.png)

Then get slug: `term-category-name` and use it in combination with other element CSS. That is.